# Chromium, execute website UI commands?

Tags: chromium

Im running Raspberry pi OS on a Raspberry pi 3. Im trying to setup so when I boot, It should start Chromium in kiosk mode on a specific site, Flightradar24. So far so good. But I would like it to choose some different options in the website UI. Is that possible even? I would like it to zoom and fullscreen so the widgets dissapear.

Any idea?

Comment: Please show us what you've done already?  You say "So far so good", does that mean that you've successfully launched Chromium in Kiosk mode?  If yes, please show us how you did that.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [`xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html)

[Here's what someone else did to accomplish your goals:](https://groups.google.com/g/xdotool-users/c/tYcz-Tb5bDI/m/1iU66ak_AQAJ)

> In my home directory (for me it is /home/pi) /.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi the autostart file is:

```
@lxpanel -profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@sed -I 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly" true /~.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
@chromium-browser -noerrdialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk http://<path to online html document #1> OR file:////<path to file on the pi>

@lxterminal --command "home/pi/scripts/sleep.sh" ***This is where I launch xdotool after a short delay. Xdotool always worked in a terminal window for me.
```

> My scripts reside in ~/scripts. sleep.sh uses xdotool to do a Control+Tab every 10 seconds. This moves the kiosk from one tab to the next.
>
> ***sleep.sh***

```
#!bin/bash
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class Chromium windowfocus
watch -n 10 xdotool key ctrl+Tab # This sends <crtl+Tab> every 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a browser that can be controlled programmatically.
It's meant for software testing, but it comes in handy in a scenario like yours.